# Is there array_diff (php) method analogue for Python 3.x

Tags: python, arrays

for example:

```
>> a = list(["red", "blue", "red"]);
>> b = list(["yellow", "red"]);
```

result of array_diff:

```
>> list("blue")
```

or best way to do this?

Comment: Is the order of elements in the resulting list important? If not you can convert both of them to sets and find the set difference `set(a) - set(b)`

Comment: You can use: `[item for item in a if item not in b]` and wrap this in a function, but I do not know if there is a built-in solution out of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert them to a set and do a set substraction

```
>>> a = ["red", "blue", "red"]
>>> b = ["yellow", "red"]
>>> set(a) - set(b)
{'blue'}
>>> a
['red', 'blue', 'red'] # the lists are still the same
```